# Oracle trigger implementation

Tags: database, oracle, triggers, build-triggers

I have to implement a trigger which would:

> **7) Show the DDL for how a trigger can be used to transfer all rental copies from a store being deleted from the Store information table to the central store 
>   
> 8) Show how this trigger can be extended to make
>   sure that the central store is never deleted from the database**

So far I have done this:

> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER stores
>  BEFORE DELETE ON stores
>  FOR
>   EACH ROW
>  BEGIN
>  IF DELETING WHERE cvr = 123456789 THEN
>   Raise_Application_Error (
>    num => -20050,
>    msg => 'You can
>   not delete Main Store.');
>    END IF;
>    IF DELETING THEN
>  
>   UPDATE store_id=123456789 ON movies WHERE isActive = 0
>    END
>   IF;
>    END;

so main store is with cvr which is written, but it gives me a compilation error. Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the compilation error you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two errors in your code.

1. there is no "DELETING WHERE" expression, you have to use two boolean exceptions like this:

   IF DELETING AND :old.cvr = 123456789 THEN...

`:old.cvr` refers to value of cvr column in deleted record

2. Syntax of UPDATE clause is

   UPDATE table_name
       SET column_name1 = value1,
           column_name1 = value2
     WHERE where_clause;

in your case probably somethink like this:

```
UPDATE movies 
    set store_id = 123456789
  WHERE store_id = :old.cvr
```

I guess, I don't know required functionality

Comment: on UPDATE sytax I also need to check that store_id which is old.cvr, if isActive, so I would avoid changing all movie store locations. Can I somehow reffer on UPDATE that it would check if stores isActive equals to 0?

Comment: yes, you can. Your where clause can be like this: `WHERE store_id = :old.cvr AND isActive = 0`